# every $\sigma$ algebra is a monotone class

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, monotone-class-theorem

I couldn't understand the monotone class theorem because of this lemma:
"Every $\sigma$ algebra is a monotone class."

How i can prove it?

Answer (score 6):

A $\sigma$-algebra is closed under countable union and countable intersection, so in particular under increasing countable union and decreasing countable intersection.

Comment: Thanks.I'd like to ask one more thing if my proof is correct.

"Let M be a $\sigma$ algebra and $A_{1} \subset A_{2} \subset A_{3}... $ and $A_{i}$'s are elements of M and  $\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i$=A  Because M is $\sigma$ algebra A is an element of M.Therefore M is monotone class."

Comment: @SerkanYaray that is the correct reasoning. Similarly for a decreasing sequence converging to the intersection.